# Using Power automate flow to send email with all content corresponding to it with individual email to each

Tags: automated-tests, power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector

**Power automate flow to send email to individuals**

I have following scenario,
An excel sheet with column Emp Name, ID, Item to be deleted , Item deleted, All owner.
All owner column contain emailid of one or more person. I need an output which would send email with all corresponding details to individuals

Sample:
[image]

The flow send email to individuals means for abc@xyz.com it should collect correcding detail and send in html format.

abc@xyz.com & edf@xyz.com should receive following in html:

[image]

respectively.

Please help..

Comment: can you clarify which app to use to send email, or which language are you going to use?

Comment: I am using Power Automate Flow only